# Localise position of your word in Java by Words not by Characters

Tags: java, string, indexing, position, cpu-word

guys is there a way to localise the position of a word by Word for example i've this text : "I am a human" the word is "human" so our word is in the 4th position i've a method to index by characters it's show me Index of human is :7 and this is not what i'm looking for thx guys

Comment: yes thats possible with java.

Comment: can you give a solution !

Comment: no. try it yourself and come back if you have a more specific question. small tip: use split and Arrays

Comment: i tryed i got just of the index one -_- i didn't knew anything else those are my limits

Comment: done i edited the question

Comment: you edited nothing...

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test
public void testPositionSplit() {
  String lWords = "Hi all whats up";
  String[] lAllWords = lWords.split(" ");
  int index = 0;

  System.out.println("Find:");
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  String lWordToFind = in.next();

  for (String lWord : lAllWords) {
    ++index;
    if (lWord.equals(lWordToFind)) {
      System.out.println("Word [" + lWord + "] placed at position "+index);
    }
  }
  in.close();
}
```

what gives you the output(insert up):

> Word [up] placed at position 4

Comment: Where to put the INPUT in this code for me it didn't work -_- sorry bro